# Помогите пожалуйста подправить JS код

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

```js
function look(type) {
  param = document.getElementById(type);
  if (param.style.display == "none") param.style.display = "block";
  else param.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
a {
  color: #FF610C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="display:block">
  Everest Game Pro 9095 — высокопроизводительный игровой ПК на базе процессора
  Core i7. Технология Dual Intelligent Processors – разгонный и энергетический
  процессоры TPU и EPU UEFI BIOS с поддержкой режима EZ Mode – гибкий и удобный
  интерфейс BIOS
</div>
<a href="javascript:look('div1');">Свернуть</a>
```

JS не знаю, поэтому нашел в гугле, но не совсем рабочее. + еще надо чтоб когда сворачивалось, кнопка менялась на "развернуть", и наоборот. Буду благодарен если кто поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function look(type, lnk) {
  param = document.getElementById(type);
  if (param.style.display == "none") {
    param.style.display = "block";
    lnk.innerHTML = 'свернуть';
  } else {
    param.style.display = "none"
    lnk.innerHTML = 'развернуть';
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  color: #FF610C;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="display:block">
  Everest Game Pro 9095 — высокопроизводительный игровой ПК на базе процессора
  Core i7. Технология Dual Intelligent Processors – разгонный и энергетический
  процессоры TPU и EPU UEFI BIOS с поддержкой режима EZ Mode – гибкий и удобный
  интерфейс BIOS
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="look('div1', this);">cвернуть</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Замени `&darr;` на развернуть, а `&uarr;` на свернуть.

```js
$(function() {
$(".toggle").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // do not follow the link
    $(".toggled").toggle().removeClass("toggled");
    $(this).next(".spoiler").toggle().addClass("toggled");
})
});
```

```css
.spoiler { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle 1</a>
<div class="spoiler">This is spoiler 1</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle 2</a>
<div class="spoiler">This is spoiler 2</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle 3</a>
<div class="spoiler">This is spoiler 3</div>
```

Comment: $this.parent().children('div.spoiler_toggle').toggle().is(':visible')
Вы не слышали про методы next() и siblings()?